# StarterSite Password reset page modification not going well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

The column "Email" in the db startersite is not use for email but for a "personnal number" (for a reason best left). I've added another column for email called "Courriel" (French for email)

Now the problem is if someone enters his "personnal number" to change the password, my website tries to send an email to this number, which of course fails (as it is not a valid email address).

I would like the password reset page to validate the "personnal number" and automatically send an email to the email address in the "Courriel" column of the database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
bool passwordSent = false;
var resetToken = "";
var email = Request.Form["email"] ?? Request.QueryString["email"];

Validation.RequireField("email", "Le champ numéro est obligatoire.");

if (IsPost) {
    AntiForgery.Validate();
    bool isValid = true;
    if (Validation.IsValid()) {
        if (WebSecurity.GetUserId(email) > -1 && WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(email)) {
            resetToken = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email); // Indiquez une date d'expiration pour le jeton (facultatif)
        } else {
            passwordSent = true;
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    if (isValid) {
        var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        var resetUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/PasswordReset?resetToken=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resetToken));
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var sqlquery = "SELECT Courriel FROM UserProfile WHERE email = @0";
        var mail = db.Query(sqlquery,WebSecurity.GetUserId(email));

        WebMail.Send(
            to: mail,
            subject: "Réinitialisation de votre mot de passe", 
            body: "Utilisez ce jeton pour réinitialiser votre mot de passe : " + resetToken + @". Accédez à la page <a href=""" + HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(resetUrl) + @""">" + resetUrl + "</a> pour réinitialiser votre mot de passe."
        );
        passwordSent = true;
    }
}
```

I've also tried the following, but it's still not working:

```
    if (isValid) {
        var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        var resetUrl = "http://69.70.9.54" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/PasswordReset?resetToken=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resetToken));
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var sqlquery = "SELECT Courriel FROM UserProfile WHERE Email = @0";
        Courriel = db.QueryValue(sqlquery,WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
```

I'm receiving this error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A recipient must
>   be specified.

If someone can give me a quick hint it would be very nice.

Comment: You don't do any validation on whether or not the `var mail = db.Query(sqlquery,WebSecurity.GetUserId(email));` actually returns anything.  I suspect it's NULL, hence the exception.  Have you debugged and verified that the query is working as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah I woke up this morning with an idea... Instead of refering to email = @0 I refered it to UserId = @0 and then I changed the QueryValue to Websecurity.GetUserId =D It works

```
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var sqlquery = "SELECT Courriel FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = @0";
        Courriel = db.QueryValue(sqlquery,WebSecurity.GetUserId(email));
```